# Trying move the product section below the category sections in side bar x-cart 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, x-cart

Here is the website link  http://rusticironstore.x-cart.biz/xcart5/

I have tried to move best seller product section below the category section into the sidebar, so I have enabled Layout editor mode from admin end and then I have drag best seller product below the category sections and then saved it its work but after refreshed the page, it's still showing on the top of the sidebar.

With the 2nd way, I have moved the code of best selling products below the category section but it's not worked it is showing nothing.

My site is in x-cart 5 and currently on the homepage in the sidebar the best seller products as the  Most wanted products. One more thing if I move new arrivals products to the sidebar below the category section it's working fine. Only best seller not moving below the category.

The best seller is a module in x-cart5 and from the back end, there are only one options how many products you want to display on front end. Below is the code of best sellers products showing in sidebar

```
<div class="{{ this.getBlockClasses() }}">
  {% if this.getHead() %}
    <!--h3>{{ t(this.getHead()) }}</h3-->
    <h3>MOST WANTED</h3>
    <div class="tag_line3">These are the hot sellers Look Below to see the most Wanted items on the site are.</div>
  {% endif %}
  <div class="content">{% include this.getBody() %}</div>
</div>
```

any x cart 5 experts please help me.

Answer (score 0):

ok so I have found the solutions with javascript to move div content with each other in my case like below

```
$('.block-bestsellers').insertAfter($('.block-flyout-categories-menu'));
```

if anybody has the same problem go to your admin end   **->look&feel->custom javascript**   and paste the above javascript code then save if your classes is not same then you need to match your classes.

thanks